# WhatsApp sharing not working in UIActivityViewController iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, whatsapp

When I share a link by what's app using UIActiviyViewController then it show a blank tableView?

```
UIActivityViewController *ACVcontroller =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[text,tinyURL,append]
                                                                                      applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:ACVcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: With WhatsApp AFAIK you can ONLY share EITHER an image or some text.

Comment: Sir i am sharing only text

Comment: "What's App" means some totally different as "WhatsApp".

Comment: What's showing a blank view? WhatsApp or your app? Can you post the code from which you show the UIActiviyViewController?

Comment: I update the code... sir

Answer (score 0):

USe whatsapp API:  http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

for Sending only Text from Objective-C try this

```
NSString * msg = @"YOUR MSG To Share";
NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
} else {
    // Cannot open whatsapp
}
```

Comment: on whatsapp sharing button

Comment: I use the UIActivityViewController Sir

Comment: use this code in the method/function from where you call for whatsapp sharing action